# ~/.rvm/bin/rvm Vs ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm new to ruby, and just wondering what is the difference between ***~/.rvm/bin/rvm*** and ***~/.rvm/scripts/rvm***

when installing ruby as described here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ I noticed that the following line was added to my .bashrc file

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

But when I tried to install some gems, they get installed but when invoking them it asks me to install the gem again.

I found that the documentation at https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/ instructs to add the following line to the .bashrc file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Once added, everything is working.

So what is the difference between these two confusing rvm scripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`bin/rvm` - this is just a wrapper to source `scripts/rvm` and run `rvm $@`

to see how to use RVM watch this: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm